# Doing iterative function before recursion implementation

Tags: c, recursion

I'm studying for an exam in C, and I struggled today implementing what I was told with recursion, I did implement it with iterative function though, and then I somehow discovered that I could easily make it recursive. for example: (the purpose of the function is to find from right to left the chars betweem 0-9, transform them from char to int and print them in that order)

**Example:**

```
char chArray[] = { '2','4','e','b','c','@','0' };
    printf("%d", buildNumber_rec(chArray, 7));
```

**Iterative:**

```
int buildNumber(char chArray[], int n){
    int i,num=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(chArray[i]>='0' && chArray[i]<='9')
            num=10*num + (chArray[i]-'0');
    return num;
}
```

**Recursive:**

```
int buildNumber_rec (char chArray[], int n){
    char last=chArray[n-1];
    if(!n) return 0;
    if(last>='0' && last<='9')
        return (last-'0')+10*buildNumber_rec(chArray,n-1);
    return buildNumber_rec(chArray,n-1);
}
```

**Output:**

```
240
```

I know it sounds too general, but is it possible to get the idea of how to solve recursive exercises by first implementing them with iterative function? In other words, discovering the pattern of how to solve recursively by first doing iteratively (If, of curse, this is my only choice - meaning, I don't know how to solve it recursively).

Comment: Think of recursion like iteratively operating with a stack data structure.

Comment: "how to solve recursive exercises by first implementing them with iterative function" - not so clear what does this mean, mind to elaborate?

Comment: @Ian I first wrote the first function, and suddenly I saw that the recursion function follows the same logic.

Comment: Note that if `n` is 0, `charArray[n-1]` is undefined. Do the test first.

Comment: @Ian This is exactly what I mean.

Comment: It's possible, at least sometimes (as you've showed yourself). There's no general "formula" that I'm aware of, and if you had written your iterative solution differently you may not have discovered your recursive solution. (It's possible to obfuscate the iteration quite a bit if you put your mind to it...)

Comment: Normally one tries to avoid recursion and does it the other way around: re-implement a recursive algorithm using iteration. Reason is to get rid of the stack. Modern compilers typically automatically convert tail-recursion to an iterative loop.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS OK, given your example and my own experience. Short answer is: I think it is *possible*, but I am not sure if it is *always* possible

Comment: Any recursive function can be write iteratively. The reciprocal is also true (and easier to demonstrate).

Comment: Here you have tail recursion, that means that you call the function recursively at the **end** of the function. In that case you can easily convert it into an iterative version (modern may do this for you) and it is perfectly pointless to use recursion here it slower than the iterative version. If the recursive call is in the middle of the fun ction, then it's more difficult to convert it into an interative version.

Comment: Note that if the example function is intended to find the desired characters *from right to left*, as you say, then the example output appears to be in the wrong order.  This is relevant because the right-to-left ordering is more convenient for a recursive implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something iteratively first is fine to help you gain an understanding of the solution to a problem. Once you understand that, then you can refactor it to a recursive function later on. If that helps you understand everything, then that is fine. Understanding what is going on is the important part, not which order you do it in.